# Orbeon XForms: repeated grid add new row issue

Tags: orbeon, xforms

When I click the default add button in the upper left corner of the repeated grid it does not add a new row. 
My model is the following:

```
<form><myproject>
    <CalcAdditionalServices>
        <CalcAdditionalService>
            <AdditionalServicesCode>d</AdditionalServicesCode>
            <AdditionalServicesSurcharge>1</AdditionalServicesSurcharge>
            <AdditionalServicesReason>Reason</AdditionalServicesReason>
        </CalcAdditionalService>
        <CalcAdditionalService>
            <AdditionalServicesCode>e</AdditionalServicesCode>
            <AdditionalServicesSurcharge>2</AdditionalServicesSurcharge>
            <AdditionalServicesReason>Reason</AdditionalServicesReason>
        </CalcAdditionalService>
    </CalcAdditionalServices>
</myproject></form>
```

I have the following binds

```
<xf:bind id="CalcAdditionalServices-bind" ref="CalcAdditionalServices" name="CalcAdditionalServices">
     <xf:bind id="CalcAdditionalService-bind" ref="CalcAdditionalService">
         <xf:bind id="AdditionalServicesCode-bind" ref="AdditionalServicesCode"/>
         <xf:bind id="AdditionalServicesReason-bind" ref="AdditionalServicesReason"/>
         <xf:bind id="AdditionalServicesSurcharge-bind" ref="AdditionalServicesSurcharge" name="AdditionalServicesSurcharge" type="xf:decimal"/>
    </xf:bind>
</xf:bind>
```

and the following repeated grid:

```
<fr:section id="CalcAdditionalServices-control" bind="CalcAdditionalServices-bind">
    <fr:grid id="CalcAdditionalService-grid"
             repeat="true"
             bind="CalcAdditionalService-bind"
             template="instance('fr-form-instance')"
             min="0" >
        <xh:tr>
            <xh:td>
                <xf:select1 xmlns:xxbl="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xbl" 
                                    id="AdditionalServicesCode-control"
                                     bind="AdditionalServicesCode-bind"
                                     class="">
                    <xf:itemset nodeset="instance('fr-form-instance')//Entity[@type='AdditionalServices']">
                        <xf:label ref="Description[@language='de']/text()"/>
                        <xf:value ref="@code"/>
                    </xf:itemset>
                </xf:select1>
            </xh:td>
        </xh:tr>
    </fr:grid>          
</fr:section>
```

First, I would like to populate the repeated grid(is working) and then the user is allowed to add a new row (which is not working)

Comment: Did you make any changes by hand in the form? Which version of Orbeon Forms are you using?

Comment: I created the repeated grid by hand, all the binds refer to my model. We are using version 4.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you use `template="instance('fr-form-instance')"`. This is probably not the template you are looking for.

The template must only contain the bit that will be inserted to create a new repeat iteration. So:

```
<xf:instance id="CalcAdditionalServices-template">
    <CalcAdditionalService>
        <AdditionalServicesCode/>
        <AdditionalServicesReason/>
        <AdditionalServicesSurcharge/>
    </CalcAdditionalService>
</xf:instance>
```

And the you would refer to it with:

```
template="instance('CalcAdditionalServices-template')"
```

This said, I think you are looking for trouble doing this by hand. This is really designed to be produced by Form Builder.

But if you still want to do it by hand, your best bet is to use Form Builder first, look at the code it generates, and then follow that very closely.

Comment: That's what I did (which I have mentioned above) and it is not working. I will update my question to be more specific.

Comment: I don't see where you mention that. I look at your binds and they are not nested.

Comment: Ooops! I tried to minimize the example and by mistake I added the "/" character.

Comment: I updated my question. Maybe it was not clear that first I populate the repeated grid.

Comment: Have you tried the changes with the template first? If so, can you please try?

Comment: When I add a repeated grid using Form Builder, it creates a grid section in my model and I can add new rows. I tried also with the different template you mentioned. It is also working. The problem is that data are in the other template. How can I populate the repeated grid and then add new rows?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "populate the repeated grid and then add new rows". The idea of the grid control is that it inserts new, empty rows. Which data are you looking to have in new rows?

Comment: During the initialization of the form i want the rows to be shown and then to enable user to add new rows (2 rows mentioned in the model, my model isn't static. It can have more or less data). There is no problem to insert empty rows, I can leave with it.

Comment: I added my namespaces to the different template('CalcAdditionalServices-template') you mentioned. Thanks for your help and patience ebruchez